# FFMPEG Multistream WMV

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, encoding, ffmpeg, wmv

I need a program for Ubuntu Lucid that can covert a video file to a multistream WMV. I have been looking into FFMPEG, but I can cannot figure out how to do several streams in a single WMV. Currently on Windows I use WMEncoder 9, but am looking to automate the process via a script on a Linux box.

Comment: when you say multistream WMV what do you mean? different audio and video inputs or multiple audio streams / multiple video streams...very different questions

Comment: I have a single high res video with audion I need to convert to a single WMV with a high res video / audio set and a lower quality video / audio set.